# True forms vs. pseudo-forms/Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

In the setting of differentiable manifolds, what is the difference between
**true forms** and **pseudo-forms**? Is one a special case of the other ?
Which direction holds ?

[image]

Comment: In 45+ years of working with differential forms, I've never heard of pseudo-forms. Do you mean densities? Do you mean forms with values in a vector bundle? Please give a definition.

Comment: @TedShifrin Please see Frankel's book the Geoketry of physics, page 86. Do you know that book ?

Comment: I looked at the book many years ago, but have retired and no longer have access to a library. Please make your question self-contained.

Comment: @TedShifrin You may consider and appreciate [this link](http://93.174.95.29/main/924000/a7d815ef0b102d13a050e99680db0050/Theodore%20Frankel%20%20-%20The%20geometry%20of%20physics%20_%20an%20introduction-Cambridge%20University%20Press%20%282004%29.djvu)

Comment: @TedShifrin If you cannot open a djvu file you may see my EDIT.

Comment: Oh, pseudo-form like the physicists' pseudo-vector. Indeed, as Frankel says, deRham called these by a different name. Pseudo-forms are twisted differential forms (twisted by the orientation). They are two different (although closely related, of course) objects — a form is not a pseudo-form and a pseudo-form is not a form.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the clarification. Is it somehow true that $\alpha_O$ is close to zero somewhere in order to be smooth ?

Comment: No, no. Think of the volume pseudo-form on an orientable manifold. It is nowhere-vanishing. Once you orient the manifold, then this becomes a differential form.

Comment: @TedShifrin And what if the manifold is **non-orientable** then the pseudo-form must vanish somewhere right ?

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you recommend a book that discusses the construction of pseudo-forms formally? As far as I can understand one takes $\Lambda^k V^* \otimes  Or(V)$, but I can't find a formal treatement of this (Frankel's book is not exactly formal).

Comment: @lightxbulb I retired 8+ years ago and gave away most of my library, so I really cannot help. You might try Abraham and Marsden. You can also see *twisted cohomology* discussed in Bott and Tu's *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*. Twisted forms even appear in DeRham's seminal *Differentiable Manifolds: Forms, Currents, Harmonic Forms*, but that may be too old-fashioned for you.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the references!